# Record how long a user is modifying a form in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm using Access as a front end to SQL Server. We have a split form where the users select a record, insert some new information with the form, then continue on to the next record. My manager would like to see how long it takes a user to modify a record. So I would like a timer to start when someone clicks on a record then it to stop when they click on the next record or when they select complete in the form. I would like this imformation exported to an excel sheet. It might be easier to get the average time for each user since most users are modifiying over 100 records per day. Is there anyway this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple solution : you can write a function in the **On Dirty** event of the form and add a record to a table with current record's ID,Username and current time (starting time).
in the **On AfterUpdate** of the form use a function to update the same record and add current time as (Ending time). 
When a user starts editing or adding a record, the time is registered in this table. when he/she updates the record, the time is added as ending time.

Now you have a table which contains ID, username, startTime, endingTime. with a query, you can calculate how much time is spent for each record, starting from editing, ending to updating. You can export this table to a excel sheet whenever you need.

the complex method:

I had a similar situation. I was asked to close the database if the user is idle for a specified time (for network traffic problems)

I used the bellow function in timer event of the form. It reads the name of the active form every 5 seconds and saves it in a static variable. this function compares Screen.activeform.name with this static variable every 5 seconds. 
if the name of active form is different with this static variable, it shows the user is active (doing something), so it resets the timer static variable. otherwise it means the user is idle and adds the timer.

when the timer reaches to a specified amount which is set in application's option (let's say 5 min) it means that the user has been idle for 5 min and I simply run the Application.Quit and close the database.

I'm busy at present and have no time to work on it. You can modify this function to check the current record or even current control (Instead of current form) and before resetting the static timer variable, export the timer variable, username and ID of the record to a table and calculate the spent time with a query and export it to excel.

Hope it helps.

If I find a spare time this weekend, I'll try to make a simple database to show how actually it works

MyTimer:

```
' IDLEMINUTES determines how much idle time to wait for before
' running the IdleTimeDetected subroutine.

IdleMinutes = fGetOption("Machine", "AutoLogOff", False)
If IdleMinutes = 0 Then Exit Sub

Static PrevControlName As String
Static PrevFormName As String
Static ExpiredTime

Dim ActiveFormName As String
Dim ActiveControlName As String
Dim ExpiredMinutes

On Error Resume Next



    ' Get the active form and control name.

    ActiveFormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
    If Err Then
        ActiveFormName = "No Active Form"
        Err = 0
    End If

    ActiveControlName = Screen.ActiveControl.Name
    If Err Then
        ActiveControlName = "No Active Control"
        Err = 0
    End If

    ' Record the current active names and reset ExpiredTime if:
    '    1. They have not been recorded yet (code is running
    '       for the first time).
    '    2. The previous names are different than the current ones
    '       (the user has done something different during the timer
    '        interval).
    If (PrevControlName = "") Or (PrevFormName = "") _
        Or (ActiveFormName <> PrevFormName) _
        Or (ActiveControlName <> PrevControlName) Then
        PrevControlName = ActiveControlName
        PrevFormName = ActiveFormName
        ExpiredTime = 0
    Else
        ' ...otherwise the user was idle during the time interval, so
        ' increment the total expired time.
        ExpiredTime = ExpiredTime + Me.TimerInterval
    End If

    ' Does the total expired time exceed the IDLEMINUTES?
    ExpiredMinutes = (ExpiredTime / 1000) / 60
    'Debug.Print ExpiredMinutes
    If ExpiredMinutes >= IdleMinutes Then
        ' ...if so, then reset the expired time to zero...
        ExpiredTime = 0
        ' ...and call the IdleTimeDetected subroutine.
        IdleTimeDetected ActiveFormName
    End If







    Sub IdleTimeDetected(ActiveFormName As String)

        DoCmd.Close acForm, ActiveFormName

        CloseAllForms
        Application.Echo True
        Application.Quit

    End Sub
```

Comment: I really like the idea of your simple solution. I have no Visual Basic skills and have only been learning it as I try to follow already written code that has been written for the form. What do you mean by On Dirty event? I think I know/can look up what is needed to export the information to a table.

Comment: The Dirty event occurs when the contents of a form hanges. It also occurs when you move from one page to another page in a tab control.

Comment: I tried to edit, but there's a 5 min limit.

In other word when you start editing a record in a from and before saving the changes the form dirty.

you can run a sub as soon as the form gets dirty.
Open a form in design mode, press F4 to open the property sheet (it it's not already open), click the events tab in property sheet, scroll down to find On Dirty property. Click the small arrow in front of On Dirty and select Event Procedure. and click the small button with three dots (...) on it to open vb.

Comment: because the limitation in comments section, I added a new Answer above with a sample database. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple sample database to help you.

[Sample Database](http://rapidgator.net/file/657d851d174faa9dcaa319b27ad8af18/Database2.accdb.html)

This database is written in Office 2013. I hope you can open it.
Open the frm Form and start editing a record or start inserting a new record.
the starting and ending of editing/inserting of a record will be registered in **result** table. You can export this table to a excel file at the end of the day.

Be careful that this database needs some modifications.
for example you must add some codes to recognize the current username
I think you can manage this section

Comment: Ugh the content is blocked because I am at work trying to open the same database. I will try this weekend and let you know how it goes. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I ended up just doing an OnClick event that captures the time for when a user selects one of the fields and then it captures the time again when the user selects the completed field. thanks for your help!